# Hello, How to extract array of values and set it to next request one by one

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

How to extract array of values from response and set to next post request in JMETER

I tried using JSON extractor but when i set all fields populatring same value.

```
{"status":"success","mainCategories":[{"categoryName":"Comfort & Convenience","sortNo":"1","recommendedFeatures":[{"featureId":"MVS-2018-MIC-32","featureName":"Bluetooth® Hands-free Phone System","featureSortNumber":"0","videoURL":"","videoName":"","showVideo":"N","image":"","copy":"","intelligentMobility":"N","steps":[],"isCompleted":"N"},{"featureId":"MVS-2018-MIC-39","featureName":"Tilt steering column","featureSortNumber":"0","videoURL":"","videoName":"","showVideo":"N","image":"","copy":"","intelligentMobility":"N","steps":[],"isCompleted":"N"}],"optionalFeatures":[{"featureId":"MVS-2018-MIC-34","featureName":"Air conditioning","featureSortNumber":"0","videoURL":"","videoName":"","showVideo":"N","image":"","copy":"","intelligentMobility":"N","steps":[],"isCompleted":"N"},{"featureId":"MVS-2018-MIC-36","featureName":"Integrated Key with remote keyless entry","featureSortNumber":"0","videoURL":"","videoName":"","showVideo":"N","image":"","copy":"","intelligentMobility":"N","steps":[],"isCompleted":"N"}]},{"categoryName":"Instrumentation & Driver Controls","sortNo":"1","optionalFeatures":[{"featureId":"MVS-2018-MIC-33","featureName":"Trip computer (average fuel economy, current fuel economy, distance to empty)","featureSortNumber":"0","videoURL":"","videoName":"","showVideo":"N","image":"","copy":"","intelligentMobility":"N","steps":[],"isCompleted":"N"},{"featureId":"MVS-2018-MIC-40","featureName":"Cruise control with steering-wheel-mounted controls",
```

In here i have to extract the featureID and isCompleted values and set to next request. I am getting same value populating for all those 2 fields.

Comment: Please post full JSON and the required format of the next request

Comment: Next request :
  "selectedFeatures": [
    {
      "featureId": "${response}",
      "isCompleted": "${response}"
    },
{
      "featureId": "${response}",
      "isCompleted": "${response}"
    },
    {
      "featureId": "${response}",
      "isCompleted": "${response}"
    },

Comment: Does the number of selected features in your request matches the number of features you have in the response?  Is that number fixed (i.e always 5 values)?

Answer (score 1):

You requirement is not clear, i.e. JSON is malformed, criteria of "features" selection are vague, etc. so I'll try to provide the answer basing on my very limited understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
   def selectedFeatures = new ArrayList()
   json.mainCategories.each {
       category -> category.recommendedFeatures.each {
           recommendedFeature ->
               def feature = new groovy.json.internal.LazyMap()
               feature.put('featureId', recommendedFeature.get('featureId'))
               feature.put('isCompleted',recommendedFeature.get('isCompleted'))
               selectedFeatures.add(feature)
       }
   }
   json.mainCategories.each {
       category -> category.optionalFeatures.each {
           optionalFeature ->
               def feature = new groovy.json.internal.LazyMap()
               feature.put('featureId', optionalFeature.get('featureId'))
               feature.put('isCompleted',optionalFeature.get('isCompleted'))
               selectedFeatures.add(feature)
       }
   }
   builder(selectedFeatures: selectedFeatures.collect())
   vars.put('selectedFeatures', builder.toString())
   log.info(vars.get('selectedFeatures'))
   ```
3. Refer generated JSON payload as `${selectedFeatures}` where required, i.e. in the "Body Data" tab of the next [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hello Dmitri, Thank you very much for your help. really appreciate it. But one question if i want to set it up one value for per one field how can i do so ?

Comment: Dmitri T can you suggest how to grab individual feature id and isCompleted values and set it on next request. for exmaple i have all featureId's and isCompleted's has to populate in request in induividual fields. Please help me

Comment: Can anyone help me

Comment: No one "can help you" unless you specify what do you need in clear concise form.

Comment: I have posted the full JSON request pls check all i need those featureId's and Iscompleted fields have to extract from response and set it up to those fileds sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

{ "opportunityKey": "${opportunityKey}", "activityType": "${activityType}", "pdfLanguageCode": "${languageCode}", "countryCode": "${countryCode}", "division": "${division}", "salesUserID": "${userId}", "salesUserFullName": "${salesUserFullName}", "consultantImageString": "", "clientImageString": "", "selectedFeatures": [{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g1}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g1}"},{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g2}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g2}"}, {"featureId": "${regfeature_g3}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g3}" },{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g4}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g4}" },{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g5}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g5}" },{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g6}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g6}"},{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g7}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g7}" },{ "featureId": "${regfeature_g8}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g8}" }, { "featureId": "${regfeature_g9}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g9}" }, { "featureId": "${regfeature_g10}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g10}" }, { "featureId": "${regfeature_g11}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g11}" }, { "featureId": "${regfeature_g12}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g12}" }, { "featureId": "${regfeature_g13}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g13}" }, { "featureId": "${regfeature_g14}", "isCompleted": "${regcompleted_g14}" } ], "miscellaneous": [] }